# Firebase's update password method and update email method don't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, quasar-framework

I wanted to add two features to my app - changing email and changing password. However, in the console there are no errors. I received information that the password/email was changed, but when I try to sign in with the new credentials, they don't work. However, the old credentials work.

```
  const settingItem = vueRef('')

  const currentPassword = vueRef('')
  const newCredentials = vueRef('')

  const changeSetting = () => {
    const userId = getUserId()

    const currentUser = auth.currentUser

    const credentials = EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, currentPassword.value)

    if (settingItem.value == 'Username' && !newCredentials.value || settingItem.value != 'Username' && !currentPassword.value || !newCredentials.value) {
      $q.notify({
        type: 'negative',
        message: 'Fill in all fields'
      })

      return
    }

    if (settingItem.value == 'Password') {
      reauthenticateWithCredential(currentUser, credentials).then(() => {
        updatePassword(currentUser, newCredentials.value).then((response) => {
          $q.notify({
            type: 'positive',
            message: 'Password changed successfully.'
          })

        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('update error: ', error)
        })
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('re auth error: ', error)
      })
    } else if (settingItem.value == 'Email') {
      reauthenticateWithCredential(currentUser, credentials).then(() => {
        updateEmail(currentUser, newCredentials.value).then(() => {
          $q.notify({
            type: 'positive',
            message: 'Email changed successfully.'
          })

        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('update error: ', error)
        })
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('re auth error: ', error)
      })
    } else if (settingItem.value == 'Username') {
      console.log('username')
    }
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?